# Problem using XSL to produce PDF in JAVA. No LayoutManager maker for class class org.apache.fop.fo.flow.TableAndCaption

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Got a problem using XSL to produce PDF in JAVA.
Always get "No LayoutManager maker for class class org.apache.fop.fo.flow.TableAndCaption".
Here's the XSL source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="2.0" media-type="application/xslfo+xml" indent="yes" encoding="Windows-1251"/>
    <xsl:template match="RootPart">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="allPages" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="5mm" margin-bottom="5mm" margin-left="20mm" margin-right="5mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="5mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence font-family="arial" font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal" master-reference="allPages">             
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:table-and-caption table-layout="fixed" >    
                        <fo:table border-style="solid" border-width="0.3mm" border-color="black">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="97mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="97mm"/>
                            <fo:table-header>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block>TEST1</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block>TEST2</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-header>
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row height = "5mm">
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>Volvo</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>$50000</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>SAAB</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>$48000</fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:table-and-caption>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache FOP doesn't support fo:table-and-caption, yet. Just remove the element and use fo:table directly.

See also: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-object-table-and-caption

Comment: But how to center a table in the page?